# Getting Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') error while running Azure Function app

Tags: azureportal, azure-function-app

I am getting Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') error while running Azure Function app for a TimeerTrigger.

This is my function output integration: -
[function output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm9IT.png)

This it the Code I have written to store a string in Blob storage when the function is triggered:-
[code run.csx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTvnL.png)
This is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to Test the function: -
[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDmz.png)

Comment: Ok. please show your function.json. The output binding is in that place.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the connection is getting wrong. Check the  **"connection"** field in *function.json* file.

Here is the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp-script#configuration) of this field:

> The name of an app setting that contains the Storage connection string
> to use for this binding. If the app setting name begins with
> "AzureWebJobs", you can specify only the remainder of the name here.
> For example, if you set connection to "MyStorage", the Functions
> runtime looks for an app setting that is named
> "AzureWebJobsMyStorage." If you leave connection empty, the Functions
> runtime uses the default Storage connection string in the app setting
> that is named AzureWebJobsStorage.

[image]

If it is correct, navigate to your Function app and click the **Configuration** under **settings**, check the **app setting** contains your storage account **connection string**.

On my side (by default), it is AzureWebJobsStorage:
[image]