# How to send the notification to Bot using azure fucntion?

Tags: azure-functions, botframework

I have built a bot with SDK v3 C# of Bot framework and I have also implemented the proactive message the conversation id will store in the azure table and all related information. when ever the user initiate the conversation the bot will identify the user. I want to send the notification to bot service using time trigger function everyday. But i am not able to find the bot framework in output bindings of azure function app.

[image]

> ***How can i do it without bot framework as output bindings.***

**=============================Code Test======================================**
**I have tested the code and it is giving me the same error, kindly have a look.**

[image]

**==========================Integration=======================================**
Here is my integration. if i remove the **Http binding as output ERROR will remain the same**
[image]

**===============================Json file code================================**
Here is my function **json** file code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a scenario like this: Need a teams conversation bot to send proactive message to a group chat at a specific time everyday.

And my method is : Set a time trigger in function and when it triggered, my function will call an API which is created by myself and this API will execute the sending proactive message method.

Here's my function code, and wish it would help you:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");


HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/sendProactiveMesg");
request.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream myResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

}
```

============UPDATE===========

According to your error message, it seems that you have miss configuring in some place, but I don't know why it happened. I'll share my experience in creating time trigger. After saving the code, it will be triggered once a minute. If this doesn't help, could you pls describe your configuration？ Because I never met an error on time trigger on 'none value'.

[image][image]
[image]

=========================UPDATE 2 =============================
My code:
[image]

```
public async Task sendtoPersonal()
        {
            string teamInternalId = "19:3fxxx7d8c@unq.gbl.spaces";
            string serviceUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/";
            string mentionUserPrincipalName = "xxx";
            string tenantId = "72fxxxx47";
            string botClientID = "e8caxxxx8c";
            string botClientSecret = "5zxxxxJA";
            AppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
            ConnectorClient connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials(botClientID, botClientSecret), true);
            TeamsChannelAccount user2 = (await connectorClient.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(teamInternalId)).Select((ChannelAccount channelAccount) => JObject.FromObject(channelAccount).ToObject<TeamsChannelAccount>()).First((TeamsChannelAccount user) => user.UserPrincipalName == mentionUserPrincipalName);
            //Activity personalMessageActivity = MessageFactory.Text("Personal message from the Bot!");
            IMessageActivity personalMessageActivity = await showTeamStatus();
            ConversationParameters conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Members = new List<ChannelAccount>
            {
                user2
            },
                ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    Tenant = new TenantInfo
                    {
                        Id = tenantId
                    }
                }
            };
            ConversationResourceResponse response = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters);
            await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(response.Id, (Activity)personalMessageActivity);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Tiny-wa for replying   I am getting an time trigger error                                                           _Executed 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' (Failed, Id=fd6e4f57-1499-4283-8118-87077e57b6c8, Duration=1ms)Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')_      DO i need to update **JSON** file and **output bindings** as http?

Comment: @Aaditya I've updated my answer on your error message, and I'm willing to know more details if that doesn't work.

Comment: i have the same configuration i have created a function again according to the screenshots you provided. But i am getting the same error. I will update a screenshot in my question. Do i need to update my **JSON** function

Comment: Thanks @Tiny-wa  I am not sure about that how to call my BOT api in browser.  I was trying to send the message to bot on direct line i was successful in postman webiste but i am not sure how to bind the header and body to an http POST request. My bot conversation id are store in azure storage table

Comment: Hi, in my opinion, you've implemented sending proactive message to the user, it means that your backend program has a method to get conversationId and other necessary parameters and use these parameters to send proactive message. So the 'API' I mean above is creating a method to call the method above and expose this method as a API. I'll show my API in answer. Just a minute.

Comment: Thanks @Tiny-wa so after implementing this method i need to update the http request in your provided code to xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/sendtopersonal RIGHT?

Comment: @Aaditya Just trying it. My solution is upon your own code. My method 'sendtoPersonal' is used to send proactive message. And I wanna this method to be called by a time trigger, so I created another method with the route 'api/sendProactiveMesg', and when I visit 'https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/sendProactiveMes', a message will send to someone by my bot. And the same scenario as the url be called by a time trigger.

Comment: I have also tested it and it works fine on sample bot by triggering this on my browser. The issue remains now is--> Time Trigger function is giving the same error as in screenshot I uploaded. How can we resolve that issue?

Comment: If you can trigger your method on your browser with correct response(I mean code is ok and send message correctly), then just compare the screenshots above. I have posted my function code and integration and function.json, trying to keep them all the same? Or restart the trigger?

Comment: i created a new time trigger function and executed the Test/Run also i have applied not code at all just a fresh function. when i executed, it gave me same error (Parameter cannot be null) the code we are adding is Correct so what can be the issue now?

Comment: Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591810/getting-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-connectionstring-error-while-running)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226072/discussion-between-tiny-wa-and-aaditya).

Comment: I have successfully completed the task by using power automate just triggring the link every one minute and it is send the msg every minute in teams bot. Thanks @Tiny-wa

Comment: @Aaditya Long time no see bro, and congratulations !

Comment: yup bro @tiny-wa